# How can i add a review useful vote system in magento?

Tags: magento, voting-system, review

I want to add a thumbs up / thumbs down system to the magento review system and don't quite know where to start. What are the files that control the review and how would I go about extending it to fit my needs ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is extension on Magento Connect [which](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/detailed-review-6492.html) have similar (actually I guess only wording differ) functionality. You could install/download it and check source. You could check demo [here](http://mage-workshop.com/sony-vaio-vgn-txn27n-b-11-1-notebook-pc.html). Note "Was this review helpful?" at the bottom of review block.

Comment: Pretty cool module! I needed a simpler one but this might come in handy some day. I wound up adding just the thumbs up/down to the core review module and it works OK for what I needed it to do.